# Does this set can say more about group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, set $\Omega=\{H\leq G\mid N_G(H)=H\}$

It is easy to observe followings;

- $|\Omega|=1$ if and only if $G$ is nilpotent as normalizer grows in nilpotent groups.
- For $H\in \Omega$, $Z(G)\leq H$
- $K=\bigcap\limits_{H\leq \Omega} H$ is a characteristic group of $G$ including $Z(G)$.
- $N_G(P)\in \Omega$ for all sylow-$p$ subgroup of $G$.
- It also includes all nonnormal maximal subgroups of $G$.

My  question is that "can we say anthing about cardinality of $\Omega$ when $G$ is solvable?"
And any further observation would be appriciated.

Comment: A few minor observations: Another way to state your first point (which requires $|G| < \infty$): $|\Omega| = 1$ iff $\Omega$ contains no maximal subgroups. A generalization of your 4th point: if $H$ is characteristic in $N_G(H)$, then $N_G(H) \in \Omega$

Comment: If $H$ is nilpotent and $N_G(H) = H$, then $H$ is called a Carter subgroup of $G$. A result of Carter states that if $G$ is a finite solvable group, then $G$ contains Carter subgroups and all such subgroups are conjugate.

Comment: If your question relates only to finite groups then you should say so. There are lots of infinite groups around, and some of them are nilpotent!

Comment: @DerekHolt: I am mainly interested in finite case, I edited the question.

Comment: If $|G| \leq 100$ is solvable but not nilpotent, then $|\Omega|$ is in { 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 13, 14, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 26, 30, 31, 32, 36, 37, 38, 40, 42, 44, 48, 56, 57, 62, 76, 78, 106, 132, 184 }.  I don't see much of a pattern.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks $|\Omega|$ seems to be arbitrary.

Comment: One more observation: Denote $\Omega_G = \{H \leq G: N_G(H) = H\}$. Now $H \mapsto H/Z(G)$ defines a bijection from $\Omega_G$ to $\Omega_{G/Z(G)}$, so studying $\Omega$ reduces to the case $Z(G) = 1$. I don't know if we can say anything interesting in this case. But I would guess no.

Comment: Can we say  anything about $G'\cap H$ where $H\in \Omega$,